# Undefined reference when compiling libPNG example

Tags: c, libpng

I was trying out [this](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/imgProc/files/libPNG/makePNG.c) libPNG example, but it failed at compilation. I used `gcc -lm -lpng makePNG.c` to compile it and got the following error:

```
/tmp/ccgGO8zw.o: In function `writeImage':
makePNG.c:(.text+0x360): undefined reference to `setRGB'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I removed the function definitions and simply moved the functions so that they were in the following order:

```
void setRGB(png_byte *ptr, float val)
int writeImage(char* filename, int width, int height, float *buffer, char* title)
float *createMandelbrotImage(int width, int height, float xS, float yS, float rad, int maxIteration)
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

And it worked. My question is: why didn't it work before? SetRGB was defined prior to writeImage, so how could the 'setRGB' reference be undefined?

Edit:

I forgot to mention something that I now realize is very important. I removed the 'inline' keyword from the setRGB function. I tried compiling with the inline keyword and it had the same error message. So clearly my issue has to do with the inline keyword and not the forward declarations like I originally thought...

Comment: Example compiles and builds fine see [Resulting .png](http://paste.opensuse.org/25917281) Try `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o libpngex libpngex.c  -lm -lpng` and then run `./libpngex output.png`

Comment: The `inline` keyword is just a "*hint*" to the compiler that it can inline the function. There is no guarantee it does it. But, you must be consistent between the function *declaration* and function *definition*. You cannot have `inline` on one and not the other -- they will be seen as two different functions.

Comment: @David C. Rankin I've run again with your command and I get the following message:

Comment: sam@debian:~/code/test$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o libpngex makePNG.c -lm -lpng
makePNG.c: In function ‘writeImage’:
makePNG.c:78:6: warning: variable ‘code’ might be clobbered by ‘longjmp’ or ‘vfork’ [-Wclobbered]
  int code = 0;
      ^~~~
makePNG.c:81:12: warning: variable ‘info_ptr’ might be clobbered by ‘longjmp’ or ‘vfork’ [-Wclobbered]
  png_infop info_ptr = NULL;
            ^~~~~~~~
makePNG.c:82:12: warning: variable ‘row’ might be clobbered by ‘longjmp’ or ‘vfork’ [-Wclobbered]
  png_bytep row = NULL;

Comment: Sorry @sam you were confused. The name of my source was `libpngex.c`. Just use your `makePNG` instead, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o makePNG -lm -lpng makePNG.c`  And then run `./makePNG somepng.png`

Comment: If you look at the comment I just posted, you'll see that I already changed from libpngex.c to makePNG.c.

Comment: What you posted was `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o libpngex makePNG.c -lm -lpng makePNG.c`. Get rid of one of the `makePNG.c` in there and your output will be in `libpngex` or get rid of `libpngex` and remove the `'.c'` from the first `makePNG.c`.

Comment: The code works with the command you gave, but I don't understand why `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o makePNG -lm -lpng makePNG.c` words and the original command doesn't. There is no need to change the OUTPUT FILE to "libpngex" as I already changed the INPUT FILE to "makePNG.c."

Comment: If you look closely at the command you posted `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o libpngex makePNG.c -lm -lpng makePNG.c` you included `makePNG.c` **twice**. That is what led to the `‘code’ might be clobbered...` warnings.

Comment: That is correct, thanks for fixing that for me.

Comment: No problem, just remember `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o` **outputfile** **sourcefile(s).c ...** `-llibraries`.  And you may want to add `-Wshadow` to catch any variable shadowing.. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` enables near full warnings -- and don't accept code until it compiles without a single warning `:)`

Comment: @David C. Rankin I've answered my own question with more detail about why the original command didn't work if you're interested. I'll make sure to alias gcc with some of the options you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to David C. Rankin I have found a command that works to compile this. `gcc -Ofast -lm -lpng makePNG.c` works because it includes the -Ofast option. This is the description of that option in `man gcc`:

> -Ofast
>
> Disregard strict standards compliance.
>
> -Ofast enables all -O3 optimizations.  It also enables optimizations that are not valid for all standard-compliant programs.  It turns on
>              -ffast-math and the Fortran-specific -fno-protect-parens and -fstack-arrays.

I suspect the way the author uses inline does not comply with the c specification, and that's why it won't compile without this option. Needless to say it is never OK to write code that doesn't comply with the c standards.

Edit:

Proof that the -Ofast option is the culprit:

```
$ gcc -Ofast -lm -lpng makePNG.c
$ gcc -lm -lpng makePNG.c
/tmp/cc2JlymP.o: In function `writeImage':
makePNG.c:(.text+0x360): undefined reference to `setRGB'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$
```

Comment: The actual issue is in the use of `setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr))`. Have a look at the last sentence in the `man page` "
`setjmp()` and `sigsetjmp()` make programs *hard to understand and maintain*. If possible, an alternative should be used." This code will compile cleanly with `-O2` or higher optimization. There were changes to `libpng` in `libpng12` and later that hid the actual `png` structure members which require the use of `png_jmpbuf`.

Comment: You are correct, it even works with -O optimization on my machine.